# Apache POI: after shiftRows() some of the cell ranges don't get extended

Tags: excel, apache-poi

The project I'm working on uses Apache POI to manage Excel output. For all the output values a number of statistical values are calculated by Excel. By default, 10 output values are expected and are written to the spreadsheet in one column. Starting from row 11, there are several rows dedicated for the above mentioned statistical summary calculations.

For instance:

```
  |                  A                |  B  |
1 |
2 |
3 |
4 |
..|
10|
11|$(AVERAGE(A1:A10))
12|$(STDEV.S(A1:A10))
13| //other statistical values (st.error, confidence intervals, etc.)
```

If the total number of output entries exceeds 10, `shiftRows()` function is used to move statistical calculations down by a number of rows that exceeds 10. By using `shiftRows()` starting from row 10, the cell range used in rows 11+ gets extended as expected. For instance, if 13 output values are produced, the cell range should become A1:A13. This is true for all rows except for standard deviation, which happens to be the second row:

```
  |                  A                |  B  |
1 |
2 |
3 |
4 |
..|
13|
14|$(AVERAGE(A1:A13))
15|$(STDEV.S(A1:A10)) // should be A1:A13
16|$(func(A1:A13))
17| //other statistical values (st.error, confidence intervals, etc.)
```

I cannot find a reasonable explanation for why it doesn't work for st.deviation row.

Comment: Unfortunately there are some known bugs related to shifting, could be yours is reported in one of these: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_id=60260%2C60072%2C59983%2C59733%2C59731%2C59677%2C59306%2C59239%2C58348%2C58221%2C57885%2C57423%2C56454%2C56123%2C55814%2C54533%2C54509%2C54470%2C54399%2C53832%2C53678%2C53320%2C46742%2C46266&list_id=153486&order=bug_id%20DESC&query_format=advanced

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? If not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr we're currently using version 3.13. I'll give a try to the latest version and report the result here.

Comment: @centic thanks for the suggestion. I'll do so if the latest version doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Apache POI from 3.13 to 3.15 has resolved the issue.
Thanks to everyone for offering your help.